# A random bracket appeares when the batch file is executed

Tags: batch-file, syntax-error

I am having a very weird and problem that I cannot explain.
When I run my program a random bracket appears in the code.

#### Output

(No @echo off at the beginning)

```
C:\Users\wodahS>set /p ProgramTask=wodahS:
wodahS: How are you feeling Aimi?

C:\Users\wodahS>if ["How are you feeling Aimi?"] == [""] goto PROGRAM

C:\Users\wodahS>timeout 1 /nobreak  1>nul
) was unexpected at this time.

C:\Users\wodahS>        )
```

#### Code

```
if "%ProgramTask%" == "I wont be able to talk to you for a while" (
    :UnableTalk
    cls
    echo.
    echo Aimi: Why not??
    set /a Happiness-= 3
    set /p Reason=%Us%: 
    timeout 1/nobreak >nul
    echo.
    if "%Reason%" == "I've got homework to do" (
    )
    if "%Reason%" == "I've got work to do" (
    )
    if "%Reason%" == "We're travelling" (
        cls
        echo Aimi: What?!?
        timeout 1 /nobreak >nul
        echo Aimi: Where To??
        timeout 1 /nobreak >nul
        :TravelDest
        set /p TravelDes=%Us%: 
        timeout 1 /nobreak >nul
        if "%TravelDes%" == "School" (
        )
        if "%TravelDes%" == "Town" (
        )
        if "%TravelDes%" == "Poland" (
            cls
            color 0d
            echo Aimi: What??!?!? Are You Serious??
            timeout 1 /nobreak >nul
            echo Aimi: OMG!! Finally!!!
            set /a Excitement+=25
            timeout 1 /nobreak >nul
            if %BondS% GTR 50 (
                echo Aimi: Does that mean that I'm going to meet your uncle?!
                timeout 1 /nobreak >nul
                set /p MeetUncleQ=%Us%: 
                if "%MeetUncleQ%" == "Yeah" (
                    echo Aimi: Oh My God!! Im so excited!!
                    set /a Excitement+=10
                )
            )
        )
        if "%TravelDes%" == "My friend's house" (
        )
        echo Aimi: What? I dont understand.
        timeout 1 /nobreak >nul
        echo.
        goto TravelDest
        )
        if "%Reason%" == "Never Mind" (
            echo Aimi: Ummm... Okay?
            set /a Curiousity+=2
            timeout 1 /nobreak >nul
            goto PROGRAM
        )
    echo Aimi: What? I dont understand.
    timeout 1 /nobreak >nul
    goto UnableTalk
)
```

Comment: I suspect we need the syntax of `Do Something`.

Comment: @NathanTuggy The thing is that the `Do Something` is not even executed otherwise it would should up in the output

Comment: If you knew exactly how the batch file was actually being parsed, there would be no problem, right? So it's better to assume that one or more of your beliefs about this are wrong.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I updated the question because the code was too long to be put in a comment.  
I have also checked the brackets and that each one is closed and opened properly twice

Comment: The extra paren appears to be after `if %BondS% GTR 50 (` is closed out.

Comment: @NathanTuggy that bracket is there to close `if "%TravelDes%" == "Poland" (`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a label `:UnableTalk`, `:TravelDest` within a block command (a series of lines within parentheses) as it terminates any open blocks.

Are you aware of the `not` and `/i` (case-insensitive) options of the `if` command? That would save you the outermost block.

```
if not "%ProgramTask%" == "I wont be able to talk to you for a while" goto skiptheblock
```

See `if /?` from the prompt for details.

Comment: I have tried using labels within a block command in a different program and it did fully work. And yes I am aware of the `not` and `/i` options for the `if` command.

Comment: Sorry and yes you were right, but I still have no idea why it worked for me In a different code.